# Will drinking alchohol and smoking cigarettes inhibits muscle growth?

Tags: bodybuilding, protein, supplements, alcohol, smoking

I've a few questions regarding the alcohol consumption, smoking and body building.

**About me:**

1. 5'5", 136 lbs.
2. Undergoing a hard weight gaining program at gym at evening.
3. Drinking `Serious Mass` two scoops per day a mass gain supplement. One between meals and another one before going to sleep.
4. And I'm pretty sure that I'm eating more and heavy than what I spend since I don't let me feel hungry all the day.

**Questions:**

1. If I drink a couple of beers on the rest day(mostly the Sunday in my case) or a 2-3 drinks of alcohol on any one of the days(for a party), will it affect my protein synthesis or muscle growth?
2. If I smoke 3 to 4 cigarettes a day but not at-least 2 hours before I hit the gym. What would be the effect?

Comment: Please search first and find related questions about [smoking](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/670/3941) and [drinking](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/2475/3941). And only ask one question per question. Smoking and drinking are very different topics affecting different parts of the body.

Comment: The question on smoking might need some better answers, that's what bounties are for and why I placed one.

Comment: Related as well: [Drink beer after gym?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/11988/3941)